# BibLaTeX Incollection: editors are not shown

Tags: biblatex

I'm working on my thesis because I have to hand it in just a few days. As many others I do the bibliography at the last minute.

Using Google a lot, I found various code-snippets, which make the bibliography look like I want it. The only problem is, that there are no editors shown in the `incollection` entries. They are replaced by a hyphen or something.

Here is what I got so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, titlepage, fleqn]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}

\usepackage{ccaption}
\captionstyle{\raggedright}

\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\renewcommand{\bflabel}[1]{\normalfont{\normalsize{#1}}\hfill}

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\emergencystretch 1.5em

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, top=20mm, left=30mm, right=30mm, bottom=20mm}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%% BIBLATEX %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[
style=authoryear-icomp, 
maxbibnames=9, 
maxcitenames=2, 
uniquelist=false,
backend=biber]{biblatex} 

\DeclareFieldFormat{booktitle}{#1\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat{issuetitle}{#1\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat{maintitle}{#1\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1\isdot}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inbook]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inproceedings]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[patent]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[thesis]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[unpublished]{title}{#1}

\renewcommand*{\UrlFont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand*\mkbibacro[1]{#1}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
\usebibmacro{bibindex}%
\usebibmacro{begentry}%
\usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
\setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
\usebibmacro{title}%
\printlist{language}%
\usebibmacro{in:}%
\usebibmacro{editor+others}% Herausgeber (Hrsg.) statt hrsg. von Herausgeber
\setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock%
\usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
\newunit\newblock
\printfield{edition}%
\newunit
\iffieldundef{maintitle}
{\printfield{volume}%
\printfield{part}}
{}%
\newunit
\printfield{volumes}%
\newunit\newblock
\usebibmacro{series+number}%
\newunit\newblock
\printfield{note}%
\newunit\newblock
\usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
\newunit\newblock
\usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
\newunit\newblock
\iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
{\printfield{isbn}}
{}%
\newunit\newblock
\usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
\newunit\newblock
\usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
\setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
\usebibmacro{pageref}%
\usebibmacro{finentry}} 


%\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{andothers={et \addabbrvspace al \adddot}} 

%Blockzitat
\usepackage{setspace}
\renewenvironment{quote}
{\list{}{\rightmargin\leftmargin\singlespacing\footnotesize}%
\item\relax}
{\endlist} 

\addbibresource{Bibliographie.bib}
\newcommand*\dummy[1]{}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

And this is one of my bibliography entries ... for testing.

```
@INCOLLECTION{ang2006,
author = {Ien Ang},
year = {2006},
title = {Radikaler Kontextualismus und Ethnografie in der Rezeptionsforschung.},
editor = {Andreas Hepp and Rainer Winter},
booktitle = {Kultur – Medien – Macht.},
location = {Wiesbaden},
publisher = {VS Verlag für Sozialwissenschaften.},
pages = {61-79},
owner = {SpecialGuest},
timestamp = {2012.11.12}
}
```

I really would appreciate any help on that.

EDIT:

Run the script with the following bib-file entries, and you will be able to reproduce the behaviour:

```
@INCOLLECTION{ang2006,
author = {Ien Ang},
year = {2006},
title = {Radikaler Kontextualismus und Ethnografie in der Rezeptionsforschung.},
editor = {Andreas Hepp and Rainer Winter},
booktitle = {Kultur – Medien – Macht.},
location = {Wiesbaden},
publisher = {VS Verlag für Sozialwissenschaften},
pages = {61-79},
owner = {SpecialGuest},
timestamp = {2012.11.12}
}

@INCOLLECTION{grossberg2006,
author = {Lawrence Grossberg},
year = {2006},
title = {Der Cross Road Blues der Cultural Studies.},
editor = {Andreas Hepp and Rainer Winter},
booktitle = {Kultur - Medien - Macht. Cultural Studies und Medienanalyse. 3.,
berarbeitete und erweiterte Auflage.},
location = {Wiesbaden},
publisher = {VS Verlag für Sozialwissenschaften},
pages = {23-40},
owner = {SpecialGuest},
timestamp = {2012.10.04}
}

@INCOLLECTION{grossberg1999,
author = {Lawrence Grossberg},
year = {1999},
title = {Was sind Cultural Studies?},
editor = {Karl H. Hörning and Rainer Winter},
booktitle = {Widerspenstige Kulturen. Cultural Studies als Herausforderung.},
location = {Frankfurt a. M.},
publisher = {Suhrkamp},
pages = {43-83},
owner = {SpecialGuest},
timestamp = {2012.10.04}
}
```

The editors are only shown in the Ang (2006) entry. In the other entries they are replaced by the - singn. I don't understand why BibLaTex behaves like that, but I have to turn in my thesis in just a few days. Please ... if anyone could help me on that.

Comment: I get "In: Hepp, Andreas und Rainer Winter, Hrsg. (2006)"

Comment: hm ... for some reason mine looks like this: Ien, Ang (2006). Radikaler Kontextualismus und Ethnograﬁe in der Rezeptionsforschung.
In: – Hrsg. (2006). Kultur – Medien – Macht. Wiesbaden: VS Verlag für Sozial-
wissenschaften., 61–79.

Comment: I get the same as egreg. Which version of biblatex are you using?

Comment: My .bbl file sais: % $ biblatex auxiliary file $
% $ biblatex version 2.0 $
% $ biber version 1.0 $

Comment: @CarryWhite What TeX distribution are you using? Please upgrade biblatex and biber to their last versions.

Comment: I'm using MikTex 2.9. I just updated everything there is to update using the MikTex Updater, but I stille get the same results ...

Comment: Now I got biber 1.4 and biblatex bbl format version 2.1

Comment: do you have more than one entry with the same editors?  i'm not a biblatex user, but in looking at the manual, it says that if multiple entries on the same page have the same author(s) or editor(s), the ones after the first may be replaced by a dash.  (i didn't dig far enough to determine under what conditions this happens.)

Comment: @ barbara beeton: Yes that's it. Im citing various essays from one inncollection. In cases where I cite only essay from an incollection, authors are shown correctly. But how can I change that behaviour?

Comment: Can anyone tell me how I can get BibLaTex to show the editors of an incollection every time. BibLaTex replaces the editors with an - sign, when I got several entries from one incollection...

Comment: "You can use the package option dashed=false to get rid of all dashes." as simple as that. Thanx a lot ... you saved my life !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the package option `dashed=false` to get rid of all dashes. If you want to suppress only the dashes for the editors then try in your driver definition

```
 \undef\bbx@lasthash
 \usebibmacro{editor+others}
```

(Don't forget to put `\makeatletter` before the `\DeclareBibliographyDriver`).

Btw: You are not using the correct endash in your second entry.